# After connection to Remote Destination but download 0 size vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz with wget

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have similar problem as [mentioned here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/680). But in my situation, it pup out `gzip` and `tar` error after wget download complete response.

The weird thing is that I find out my target ssh server downloaded a empty (size = 0 byte) **vscode-remote-lock.[#commit]** file. In my opinion, maybe the error of `gzip`/`tar` is caused by the empty **vscode-remote-lock.[#commit]**.

These issues cannot be solved by different versions of VS Code and Remote-SSH Extension.

I had try to download and unzip the `vscdoe-server-linux-x64.tar.gz` in my target ssh server `.vscode-server/` folder by myself. ( [Reference here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/15#issuecomment-489969139) ) Everything goes well and Remote-SSH extension on work successfully.

How can I find out the root cause and solve it ?

- VS Code version: 1.42.1
- VS CodeRemote-SSH Extension version: 0.49.0
- Local host OS version: Win 7
- Remote SSH server OS version: Ubuntu 18.04.01 image on RHEL 7.5

  > My target ssh server is a **Kubernetes Pod** equipped with `openssh-server`, `wget`, `gzip`, `tar` package on RHEL 7.5.

Screen Shot :

[image: my vscode output]